# Нет флажка Windows Hypervisor Platform в Компонентах Windows

Tags: windows, android-studio, android-sdk, windows-10, hyper-v

Мне необходимо запустить эмулятор андроида на Windows с процессором АМД, делал все по инструкциям, но нигде не смог найти необходимого флажка "Windows Hypervisor Platform", картинку прикрепляю

[image: Windows Hypervisor Platform]

Как я понял это не тоже самое, что на скрине ниже, потому, что это опции у меня были выбраны с самого начала и это не помогает

[image: Hyper-v]

У меня есть только опции как на втором скриншоте, никаких "Windows Hypervisor Platform" или чего-то подобного там нету.
Эмулятор андроида соответственно выдает ошибку

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is properly installed and usable.
```

Где найти и как найти эту пропавшую опцию?
Вот полный список того, что я вижу: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz876.jpg

Comment: _x86 emulation currently **requires hardware acceleration**_ возможно в BIOS не включена аппаратная поддержка виртуализации

Comment: иногда результат включения или выключения этой функции проявляется после перезагрузки, так же соглашусь с @DmitryKozlov что возможно нужно покопаться в биосе

Comment: я включив все это в системе получил BSOD, пришлось в безопасном режиме отключать их назад...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оно называется: Платформа низкоуровневой оболочки Windows.

Проверить включено ли можно в PowerShell:

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online
```

Или:

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName HypervisorPlatform -Online
```

(тут можно как раз и DisplayName увидеть)

Comment: О ужас, разработчики ОС Windows, за что вы так с нами?! Неужели нельзя было назвать этот пункт хотя бы Платформа Windows Hypervisor? Или перевести  документацию на русский

Answer (score 0):

В русскоязычной версии попробуйте

```
Платформа низкоуровневой оболочки Windows
```